# Need help with a  form submission using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form which looks like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","MyController FormMethod.Post)) {
 <button type="submit" value="Generate" name="action" class="button" id="btnGenerate">Generate Form</button>
 <button type="submit" value="Confirm" name="action" class="button" id="btnConfirm">Confirm</button>
}
```

and my javascript looks like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {

         var genOverlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"><div class="innerblock box-shadow"><p>Please remember to print the registration form and sign both copies.</p><div><a id="btnClose" href="#" class="button">Close</a></div></div>');

         var confirmOverlay = jQuery('<div id="overlay"><div class="innerblock box-shadow"><p>Changes can not be made to this record once it has been confirmed. Are you sure you would like to confirm this form?</p><div> <a id="btnConfirmConfirmation" href="#" class="button">Confirm</a> <a id="btnCancel" href="#" class="button button-red">Cancel</a></div></div>');

         $('#btnGenerate').click(function () {
             genOverlay.appendTo(document.body);
             return false;
         });

         $('#btnConfirm').click(function () {
             confirmOverlay.appendTo(document.body);
             return false;
         });


         $('#btnConfirmConfirmation').live('click', function () {
             // Need help on submitting the form with the input button value of btnConfirm.

             // $('#btnConfirm').submit(); does not work
             // return true;
         });

         $('#btnClose').live('click', function () {
             genOverlay.remove();
         });

         $('#btnCancel').live('click', function () {
             confirmOverlay.remove();
         });
     });
</script>
```

How would i go about implementing btnConfirmConfirmation click on the overlay to just submit the form normally with the action value of "Confirm"?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`submit` is an event handler of the form element. This should work:

```
$('#btnConfirm')[0].form.submit()
//All form elements have a property called "form" which refers to the parent form
```

If you've attached an identifier to your form, use this:

```
$('#formId').submit();               //<form id="formId" ...
$('form[name="formName"]').submit(); //<form name="formName" ...
```

Comment: Hey Rob, Do you happen to know how i should pass the value of the button "btnConfirm" in the form submit?

Comment: Yes. Change the `type` attribute of the element: `$("#btnConfirm").attr("type","hidden");`. When a form is submitted, a maximum of one button element is passed: The clicked `submit` button WITH a name attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The `.submit()` method only applies to `<form>` elements. You could add an id to your form:

```
<form id="myForm" ...>
```

Which, as you're using HtmlHelper to create it would be achieved with:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod","MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myForm" })) { ...
```

And then call the submit method (documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)) on that:

```
$('#btnConfirmConfirmation').live('click', function () {
    $('#myForm').submit();
});
```

Or you could go to the form for your button by finding the closest ancestor form element for the button:

```
$('#btnConfirmConfirmation').live('click', function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

`closest` method is documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: Your approach is a good way to do it, BUT the form is built using a HTML helper, so you'd have to add `new { id: "myForm"}` as a parameter rather than `<form id="myForm">`. You should also link to http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: How would i pass the value of the button "btnConfirm" in the form submit?

Comment: That should be passed to your Controller in the "action" parameter, shouldn't it? If you want to investigate other methods, [this](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2010/06/04/aspnetmvc-multiple-buttons-on-aform-jquery/) blog post covers calling different actions from javascript rather than using the default submit. Also look at [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2009/05/31/asp-net-mvc-multiple-buttons-in-the-same-form.aspx)